# Translating "I deserve more (than I actually earn)"

Tags: translation, word-choice

I have a problem with translating the phrase

> I deserve more [than I actually earn]

Because the only I can find is something like that:

> Ich verdiene mehr [als ich jetzt verdiene]

The problem is that because of the ambiguity of "verdienen" it could be understand also as

> I earn more (as I actually earn)

so I'm afraid I could be misunderstood.

How should I translate that phrase?

Answer (score 5):

> Ich hätte mehr verdient als ich aktuell bekomme.

would be a common way of saying it. Oder

> Eigentlich bekomme ich zu wenig Gehalt - ich hätte mehr verdient.

If you want to confuse people, you could say

> Ich hätte es verdient, mehr zu verdienen, als ich im Moment verdiene.

While it sounds weird, it would be easier to translate back to English.

Comment: Der alte Unterschied zwischen "verdienen" und "kriegen" / "bekommen"...

Answer (score 3):

Good versions have been given. Alternatively

> Ich verdiene mehr [Gehalt] als ich bekomme / kriege.

Putting `Gehalt` would make sure the sentence is about salary.

You didn't provide context. There is also

> Mir steht mehr zu als [...]

or elevated

> Mir gebührt / schickt sich / ziemt sich [...]